# Anaconda Navigator broken: Can I still access my Jupyter notebooks, created through AN?

Tags: python

Recently I needed to clear space of my Mac (OS Catalina), and made the (foolish) decision of deleting the ‘older versions’ of anaconda navigator. All my jupyter notebooks for a year worth of lab work were created & accessed through this. Is there any way I can access them?

At the moment I can only open them through my safari search history, which seems like a very tentative solution & idk what to do. Can’t send them to myslef as it insists all the notebooks are running ?

Help appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you try to open them in Finder. Also what happens if you run them using python on the command line - with the details of what you actually run. And what do you mean by " insists all the notebooks are running ?"

Comment: When I try to open anaconda it just gives a grey question mark over it. Normally I’d open jupyter notebook through anaconda navigator which would open a tab in safari, where all the notebooks are saved, so I can’t access them or jupyter in finder. I don’t really know how to use the command line stuff :(

Comment: Unfortunately from the information you give I think you need to start from the beginning and learn a bit more how notebooks work See https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/getting-started/ for a start . Unless you used python2 which was obselete 1/1/20 so you should not have then notebooks should open in current anaconda

Comment: Perhaps too late to be useful: When you access an old notebook via history, and it opens in a browser window, the URL displayed by the browser may identify where on your HD the notebook .ipynb file is. E.g., when I create a notebook in my ~/Desktop/Temp/ folder, the URL is "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/Temp/Where%20is%20this%20notebook.ipynb". The part after "notebooks" shows the path from my home directory to the notebook (spaces in the name are encoded as %20).

Answer (score 1):

I would delete any version of Anaconda Navigator you have and then reinstall it from scratch.  Be sure to have a complete backup. Once you have reinstalled it, things should work normally.